# python segmentation fault while true:

Tags: python, while-loop, return, infinite-loop, break

I'm using the recomended adafruit library [(github)](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x.git) as described [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/software) to run neopixels using python on my raspberry pi.
this is the code i am executing this works until CLC_RUNNING AND CLC_STOP are 0 when i switch these to 1 i get the segmentation fault, is there any error with the structure of the code and do i figure out what causes the problem?!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
    strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL, LED_STRIP)
    # Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
    strip.begin()

    # Startsequence show for 5 seconds
    showSplashScreen(strip)

    # read Config File
    readConfigFile()

    print ('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

    run = True

    while run:

        # get current time from system
        now = datetime.datetime.now()

        # get current minute and second Value for color within hour
        currTimeValue = now.second + (now.minute * 60)

        # 3600 iterations per hour over Rainbow colors
        for j in range(currTimeValue, 3600):

            # if both are 1 i will get the segmentation fault
            if CLC_RUNNING == 1 and CLC_STOP == 1:
               break

            if j%10 == 0:
                readConfigFile()

            h = j / 3600.0  # every hue devided into 3600 steps

            binaryTime(strip, h)

            time.sleep(1)   #sleep for 1 second
```

Comment: Can you post the exact stack trace here as well? Thanks.

Comment: sorry i am a bit new to python, how exactly can i do that

Comment: run it, find the error message, copy it into here, and edit your post

Comment: i run it and in the terminal the last message is segmentation fault, nothing else

Comment: Oh right segfaults don't give Python stack traces because it's thrown by C... Never mind, I'll look at your code again

Comment: Have you tried with only having one of the values as `1`?

Comment: i am actually expecting it do break so both will be 1 at one point, the thing is it does break, so it stops the script from executing, but after that the last message i get from that script is the segmentation fault

Comment: Using `print("hi")` and moving it around to different locations, can you figure out which line causes it to break? As in, place the print before a line, and if it prints, move it after that line and if it doesn't print, then that line caused the problem